# .sendToDevice() works fine but not .sendMulticast() or .sendAll() - Error: tokens must be a non-empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

When I use `.sendToDevice()` with an array it works perfectly and sends a notification to all the array of tokens, but when I switch to either `.sendMulticast()` or `.sendAll()`, it fails and I get the error:

**" Error: tokens must be a non-empty array "** Even though it is not empty.

Here is the .sendToDevice() that works:

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        registrationTokens.push(data.Token);


const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "This is the Title",
            body: "This is the Body",
            badge: "1",
            sound: "default",
          },
        };

const options = {
           priority: "high",
           timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
        };

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(TokenArray, payload2, options);

}
```

The only change I make is switching the last line from `.sendToDevice()` to `.sendMulticast()` or `.sendAll()`

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: This is the code, word for word, the only difference is switching from .sendToDevice() to .sendMulticast()

Comment: `sendAll()` and `sendMulticast()` take very different arguments compared to `sendToDevice()`. You cannot just change the method name and expect it to work. See the examples in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices

Comment: Will using sendToDevice() and feeding it an array of tokens cause problems down the line? Or I guess what are the advantages of using sendAll() or sendMulticast() instead.

Comment: `sendToDevice()` uses an old/legacy backend system for delivering notifications. `sendAll()` and `sendMulticast()` use the latest FCM backend APIs, and therefore are more up-to-date and more actively maintained. These APIs also have better language support (supported in Node.js, Java, Python and more).